# Is the timestamp for a Google Form response event always the same as the timestamp in the linked spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

if I get a timestamp for a Google Form submit event, using for example:

```
var timestamp = event.response.getTimestamp();
```

a time is returned e.g.

> Fri Sep 26 17:54:02 GMT+12:00 2014

and in the linked spreadsheet the timestamp 
is displayed in column one.

Are both timestamps always identical (i.e. is the event timestamp passed to the spreadsheet) or can they be different and the timestamp on the spreadsheet is actually the timestamp of the write to the spreadsheet?

Background:  I'm making an application where when a form is submitted an email is sent to the person who has filled in the form with a confirm link.  Using a query url and a webapp on the form's linked spreadsheet I can get the parameters from the query url.  I now need to have a unique id to find the entry in the spreadsheet in order to to mark it as 'confirmed'.  Timestamps seem a suitable way of doing this, but better ways may exist.

Thanks in advance,

Trevor

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be any documentation or confirmation on this, but from my experience, the timestamp is not the time that the sheet is written to. I believe it's the form submit time, but I can't confirm that for you.

From reading your requirements however, it sounds as though there's the potential for failure as the timestamps won't be unique, and it's possible two people will submit the form simultaneously (though depending on the popularity of the form, this may be slim).

If you need a Unique ID for each entry to just confirm it was submitted, but don't need it for anything else, have you considered logging the 'Edit response URL'? That's unique to each submission, so there's no danger in mixing up submissions.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the suggestion.  Further experimentation showed that occasionally the timestamps were different at most by a second.  I suspect that the event times are for submitting the form and writing to the sheet.

I've found a more elegant solution that works well.  The form has a field for last name.  I've attached the onformsubmit trigger to the spreadsheet that receives the form responses.  By getting the current unix time in milliseconds and concatenating it to the lastname (eg.storr1411790175312) I have a unique ID to pass to the query string that is a link in the email.  Further, I write the unique ID value to the correct row in the receiving spreadsheet by using the event range method,  e.range,  which will always return the range that triggered the current event.  As the unique ID is generated once and used in both the email and the spreadsheet it is internally consistent.

Cheers

Trevor

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

The value of `event.response.getTimestamp()` is same as the timestamp in linked spreadsheet.

---

This is because...

It seems that spreadsheet also stores timestamp in milliseconds.
If you set custom cell format to 
`yyyy"/"mm"/"dd" "hh":"mm":"ss":"000`

you can finally make milliseconds to appear.

If you don't explicitly display milliseconds, spreadsheet automatically round it.

Ex)
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me nuts! My GAS was failing because of this. Also, as a suggestion, I was also having a problem with the deafult format due to language. My sheet was in Spanish but the date format was in English, so I was having erratic results. I would accept this as a the right answer if I could.