# How to prevent script from reprocessing rows/duplicating data when copying rows to new sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, duplicates

I have a google form with multiple sections that is used as the daily sign in form at my work.
There are 25 total sections in the form that relate to 12 main sections.

I have a script that copies the data from each row to the respective sheet for each section based on column values.

The problem I'm running into is that every time the script is run, it reprocesses data that has already been copied over, so I have multiple duplicates of the same rows.

I made a shortened and simplified sample form and linked spreadsheet to showcase my issue.

Link to the form: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXMLt4dc827MtRSSGUCTnK6X2Pyd6JqB29EHDf1Pcm4/edit?usp=sharing](https://stackoverflow.com)

Here's my code for the sample form/sheet:

```
function moveRows() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
 const data = mainSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 const processedRows = new Set();

 const sectionMapping = {
   'Guests': {
     sheetName: 'Guests',
     valueToIncludeColumnIndex: 0,
     valueToInclude: ['Guest'],
     columns: [2, 3]
   },
   'Members': {
     sheetName: 'Members',
     valueToIncludeColumnIndex: 0,
     valueToInclude: ['Member'],
     columns: [4, 5, 6]
   },
   'Youth Programming': {
     sheetName: 'Youth Programming',
     valueToIncludeColumnIndex: 6,
     valueToInclude: ['Youth Programming'],
     columns: [8, 9]
   },
   'Phone Log': {
     sheetName: 'Phone Log',
     valueToIncludeColumnIndex: 6,
     valueToInclude: ['Phone Log'],
     columns: [10, 11, 12]
   }
 };

 for (let rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < data.length; rowIndex++) {
   if (processedRows.has(rowIndex)) {
     Logger.log(`Row ${rowIndex + 1} already processed. Skipping...`);
     continue;
   }
   const sectionColumnIndex = 1;
   const section = data[rowIndex][sectionColumnIndex - 1];


   try {
     if (section) {
       const rowDataString = JSON.stringify(data[rowIndex]);
      
       if (!processedRows.has(rowDataString)) {
         if (section === 'Staff') {
           const valueColumn7 = data[rowIndex][6];
          
           let matchedSection = '';
          
           if (valueColumn7 === 'Youth Programming') {
             matchedSection = 'Youth Programming';
           } else if (valueColumn7 === 'Phone Log') {
             matchedSection = 'Phone Log';
           }
          
           if (matchedSection) {  
             if (!processedRows.has(`${matchedSection}-${rowIndex}`)) {
               const { sheetName, columns } = sectionMapping[matchedSection];
               const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
               const rowData = columns.map(index => data[rowIndex][index - 1]);
               sheet.appendRow(rowData);
               Logger.log(`Row ${rowIndex + 1} - Transferred to Sheet: ${sheetName}`);
               processedRows.add(rowIndex);
             } else {
               Logger.log(`Row ${rowIndex + 1} already processed. Skipping...`);
             }
           } else {
             Logger.log(`Row ${rowIndex + 1} - Section not found on column 7.`);
           }
           continue;
         }
        
         Logger.log(`Processing Row ${rowIndex + 1} - Section: ${section}`);
          // Find all sections in the sectionMapping where the condition is met
         const matchedSections = Object.keys(sectionMapping).filter(key =>
            sectionMapping[key].valueToInclude.includes(section.trim())
          );

          Logger.log(`Matched Sections: ${matchedSections.join(', ')}`);

          if (matchedSections.length > 0) {
            matchedSections.forEach(matchedSection => {
              const { sheetName, columns, valueToIncludeColumnIndex, valueToInclude } = sectionMapping[matchedSection];


              // Check if the value in the specified column matches the expected value
              if (data[rowIndex][valueToIncludeColumnIndex] !== valueToInclude[0]) {
                Logger.log(`Row ${rowIndex + 1} - Section: ${section} - Value does not match: ${data[rowIndex][valueToIncludeColumnIndex]}`);
                return; // Skip to the next iteration
              }

              const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
              const rowData = columns.map(index => data[rowIndex][index - 1]);
              sheet.appendRow(rowData);
              Logger.log(`Row ${rowIndex + 1} - Transferred to Sheet: ${sheetName}`);


              processedRows.add(rowIndex);
              processedRows.add(rowDataString);
          }); 
          }
        }
     }
   } catch (error) {
     Logger.log(`Error processing row: ${rowIndex + 1}: ${error}`);
   }
 }
}
```

I've tried using time-based, onFormSubmit, onChange triggers, but they all result in the same.

I also cannot use onFormSubmit trigger due to the risk of more than one person submitting the form at the same time.

Comment: The simple answer is to keep track of when you last processed that range of data whether it be a row or a column or possibly a table of some kind.  Beyond that it's up to you to design a system that works for you and your programming style

Comment: If your dealing with form responses you would be wise to us the onFormSubmit trigger and processes as the are entered and leave the form response sheet alone as a backup for you data.  But also you can keep in mine that column one is a time stamp so you can also keep track of that to avoid repeating old results.  But I favor the use of the onFormtSubmit trigger.  Check out the documenation for triggers it is well documennted

Comment: First, you have a unique Identifier (time) for every submission as Cooper  pointed out. Second "why" are you doing this? You have your raw data in `'Form Responses 1'` why not simply have a QUERY or FILTER in the other sheets to return whatever subset you want? What is the use case for moving the data around? Did I miss something?

Comment: @Cooper Because we are using this google form to track our daily sign ins at my work, it is difficult to use the onFormSubmit trigger, due to the fact that multiple people may submit the form at the exact same time (we have 6 sign in stations so the chance of it happening is high) and I don't want to risk missing some of the data. I was also encountering issues with the timestamp in the original linked form which is why I imported the range to the new form without the timestamp and am running the script off that one.

Comment: @Blindspots I was using a query, and I still might. I just didn't want to have a bunch of blank columns from all the other sections in each sheet and have to hide the columns. I'd prefer it to be cleaner but yeah that is is still something I'm considering if I can't make this work

Comment: Six of one, half dozen of the other. Not sure what *cleanliness* means here. In either case you need to decide what to include/exclude. You are adding a lot of complexity and new error paths so wondered what the reasoning was.

Comment: You match the time in both sheets.  If you are having trouble with time then you solve that problem first. You need to have a unique  index to match against.

Comment: You could combine time with a random number or use any of the suggestions in this [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26071217/)